# How make to an Ul-LI menu flexible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

When we click the id item on this menu it cover some bottom menu items. Instead of that I want a flexible menu, which means the drop item do not cover any other.

```css
#demo {
  margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
  font-family:  sans-serif;
}
#demo .wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
#demo .parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 150%;
  background: #023b3b;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
#demo .parent:hover,
#demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
  background: #122112;
}
#demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
  z-index: 0;
}
#demo .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 0;
  width: 180px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
#demo .wrapper:active .content {
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 3;
}
#demo .content:hover {
  height: 123px;
  z-index: 3;
}
#demo .content ul {
  background: #339933;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
#demo .content ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#demo .content li:hover {
  background: #122112;
  color: white;
}
#demo .content li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="parent">Dashboard</div>
      </div><br> <br>  
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="parent">Apps</div>
        <div class="content">
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Inbox</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Condact</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Calender</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Other</li></a>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div><br><br>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="parent">Layouts</div>
        <div class="content">
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Header</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Aside</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Footer</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Other</li></a>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div><br><br>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="parent">Widjet</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is the code snippet's result is exactly what you get ? Or is there some thing missing?

Comment: when click on apps,the drop down menu hides layout and widget instead of that i want to show them also with drop down menu

Comment: Check this http://www.bootply.com/DglnYJTSKA

Comment: wow..!,it's really nice one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this could help you. I have added `input` and `label`.

```css
#first {
  float:left;
  width:15%;
  color :bisque; 
  border-color: #023b3b;
  border-style : solid;
  height: 100%;
  background-color :#023b3b;
}

#boa{
  height: 5%;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.bob{
  text-indent: 200%;
  line-height: 210%;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.boc{
  text-indent: 4%;
  color : white;
  font-size: 83%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.bod{
  color:white;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 200%;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#demo {
  margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
  font-family:  sans-serif;
}
#demo .wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
}
#demo .parent {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #023b3b;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
#demo .parent:hover,
#demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
  background: #122112;
}
#demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
  z-index: 0;
}
#demo .content {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 180px;
}
#demo .wrapper input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0
}
#demo .wrapper:hover input[type=radio]:checked + .content {
  height: 120px;
}
#demo .content:hover {
  height: 123px;
  z-index: 3;
}
#demo .content ul {
  background: #339933;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
#demo .content ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#demo .content li:hover {
  background: #122112;
  color: white;
}
#demo .content li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="first" style="float:left; lngth:60%; ">
    <p><img src="image1.jpg"  id="boa"><span class="bob">First</span></p>
    <p class="boc" >Main</p>
    <div id="demo">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="parent">Dashboard</div>
      </div><br> <br>  
      <div class="wrapper">
        <label for="apps"  class="parent">Apps</label>
        <input type="radio" name="menu" id="apps" />
        <div class="content">
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Inbox</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Condact</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Calender</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Other</li></a>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div><br><br>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <label for="layouts" class="parent">Layouts</label>
        <input type="radio" name="menu" id="layouts" />
        <div class="content">
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Header</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Aside</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Footer</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Other</li></a>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div><br><br>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="parent">Widjet</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="boc">Componets</p>

    <p class="boc">Help</p>
    <p class="bod">&nbsp; Documents</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your effort,it satisfies the flexible menu condition.but the select menu is not working properly,it work  on click once and then it work on hover too.

Answer (score 0):

You add code in jquery:

```
   $("#demo").hide();
     $(".boc").click(function(){
     $("#demo").slideToggle();
   });
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/dreamhunter/pen/zBbdZR?editors=1100i didn't get any improvement.,when click on apps,the drop down menu hides layout and widget instead of that i want to show them also with drop down menu

Comment: you change $("#demo").toggle(); to $("#demo").slideToggle();

Comment: bro i can't find any thing new